# Segment.io `analytics.page` not sending to Google Analytics in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I'm following Segment's quickstart guide at: https://segment.com/docs/libraries/analytics.js/quickstart/

Basically, Google Analytics is **not receiving any page views** from Segment and I can't figure out why...

In my `layouts/application` file, I have:

```
:javascript
  !function(){var analytics=window.analytics=window.analytics||[];if(!analytics.initialize)if(analytics.invoked)window.console&&console.error&&console.error("Segment snippet included twice.");else{analytics.invoked=!0;analytics.methods=["trackSubmit","trackClick","trackLink","trackForm","pageview","identify","reset","group","track","ready","alias","page","once","off","on"];analytics.factory=function(t){return function(){var e=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);e.unshift(t);analytics.push(e);return analytics}};for(var t=0;t<analytics.methods.length;t++){var e=analytics.methods[t];analytics[e]=analytics.factory(e)}analytics.load=function(t){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript";e.async=!0;e.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"cdn.segment.com/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(e,n)};analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="3.1.0";
    analytics.load('#{ENV["SEGMENT_WRITE_KEY"]}');
    analytics.page();
  }}();
```

Other notes:

- It is properly pulling in my write key environment variable
- The integration is set up on my Segment dashboard (enabled, with the correct **website tracking id** supplied)
- The `analytics.load` integration seems to be working because, in my debugger console, `analytics.Integrations["Google Analytics"]` is properly initialized

Page views **are** showing up in the Segment dashboard's Debugger page (with the path, title, etc default properties all set), but views **are not** being transmitted to Google Analytics.

I don't believe it's because any arguments are missing, because Google's `pageview` only requires *either* a `page` or `location` property, both of which are supplied by default through Segment's `page()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, we had another script that was loading the same google analytics javascript file. I have **no** idea why having a duplicate script tag created the issue, but there it is. Removing the duplicate fixed the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>
```

Comment: kevlarr, do you know some good tuts/screencasts on setting up rails + segment ? The ones I found are pretty confusing. Can't even decide to implement it on frontend or backend.